# How to prevent user inputs less than the maxlength in a textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation

I have created a textbox that inputs contact number and i set it to `maxlength = 11`. how do i prevent users from entering less than 11 digits? just only exact 11 digits. Thanksssss

Comment: google is your friend, I looked for " vb.net textbox min length ".  Take a peek at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497302/how-to-set-minimum-limit-of-a-textbox-vb-net

Comment: thanks! It's very useful to understand my problem right now. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should perform validation in the `Validating` event handler.  If the data fails validation then you cancel the event and the control will not lose focus.  You can call `ValidateChildren` before using the data, to ensure that even controls that never received focus are validated.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If TextBox1.TextLength < TextBox1.MaxLength OrElse TextBox1.Text.Any(Function(ch) Not Char.IsDigit(ch)) Then
        TextBox1.HideSelection = False
        TextBox1.SelectAll()

        MessageBox.Show($"Please enter an {TextBox1.MaxLength}-digit number",
                        "Invalid Input",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        TextBox1.HideSelection = True
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ValidateChildren() Then
        'All data is valid so it is safe to use it.
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using a [MaskedTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=netframework-4.8) - it will allow you to specify that 11 digits must be entered, and it can even have separator chars like hyphens for phone numbers. I linked to MSDN - take a look

As a side note, consider NOT using a MessageBox to give the user feedback if they enter a wrong value /incomplete phone number - message boxes are quite annoying and interrupt the flow of a user interface. The modern way is to show some highlighted warning next to the input field rather than showing something that stops user input and must be dismissed, because this interrupts the user's train of thought

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! I will not use MessageBox for validations in the future. :D

Comment: With regards to not using message boxes, you might consider using the `ErrorProvider` component.

Comment: This is really something I was in need of badly! Thank You @Caius Jard

Answer (score 0):

I've figure it out the answer:

I've set my `Txtbox.Contact` to `maxlength = 11` in the Properties Design option.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Txtbox_Contact.TextLength = 11 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Contact Number is Accepted")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please input 11 digit number!")
    End If
End Sub
```